# How to deploy selenium java on heroku google chrome

Tags: java, selenium, heroku

How to deploy java selenium on heroku, I can't find video on youtube or other tutorial, any idea ?
I tried converting python code to java code but I don't know how to do it.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--lang=en");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This is my settings before google chrome opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing to set the chrome driver path. Pass the chrome driver path to SetBinary() in the below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
options.addArgument("--disable-gpu");
options.addArgument("--no-sandbox");
options.setBinary("/path/to/chromedriver");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are tring to do this, is the Hard Coded way and you will encounter a lot of bugs along the way. So I recommend the **Driver Management Software** way.

1. Get WebDriverManager ([Github](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager), [Offical Website)](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/) and import the following library:

   ```
   import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
   ```
2. Call the **setup()** method like this:

   ```
   WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
   ```
3. Initialize the driver:

   ```
   ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   ```

Hope this helped, if you need more help; check [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/).