# Deploy Selenium driver on Heroku for an Java Application

Tags: java, selenium, heroku, heroku-cli

Can please someone help me with the Selenium Java application to be deployed on Heroku.

I understand that we need to add 2 Buildpacks

1. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.git
2. https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

After adding the buildpacks, we also need to give the path of the chromedriver.

What should be the path of chromedriver for heroku applications, I assume we cant give path of bundled chromedriver as herku wont be  running mac/window.

If someone can shed light on what should be the chromedriver path for Java application, it would be of great help. I want to run selenium job in headless mode.

Comment: I think this can help: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188795/how-to-deploy-selenium-java-on-heroku-google-chrome>

Comment: I answered this question, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71149100/15533249).